# Rails 3: submit_tag does not :confirm (while link_to does)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

Why does this correctly launch the "confirm" dialog...

```
<%= link_to "Visit Other Site", "http://www.rubyonrails.org/", :confirm => "Are you sure?" %>
```

...but not this one:

```
<%= submit_tag "Save", :confirm => "Are you sure?" %>
```

I'm using:

- Rails 3.2.12
- gem 'jquery-rails' (version: 2.2.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a pending issue/bug, see comments above.

Answer (score 1):

The `:confirm` option is deprecated, it is now going to be replaced by the data attribute. Internally, the `submit_tag` is already doing the replacement.

See the [`submit_tag` documentation and source code](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-submit_tag).

Because the data attributes rely on Unobtrusive JavaScript to be executed, you should have included jQuery JS and the Rails UJS file. Otherwise, the attribute will be visible in the source code (please check it) but will not trigger the confirmation.

Comment: Thanks. But I can confirm that a) the "data-confirm" attribute is present in both cases in the source code and b) both "//= require jquery" and "//= require jquery_ujs" are present in the "application.js" file. As far as I understand that should mean that everything necessary is there (and as I said, the link_to example *does* launch the dialog, just not the submit_tag)...

Comment: Not really, may be you don't have the XSFR protection meta tags. If the tags are there, it's definitely a JS issue.

Comment: Created a bug report here: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/issues/315 Please add your comments there if you have the same problem.