# submit_tag is not displaying confirmation box

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my `.html.haml` file I added the following `submit_tag`:

```
= submit_tag 'Set Master', class: 'btn btn-primary', id: 'btn-set-master', data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }
```

But no confirmation box is showing up when I click on the submit button.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14898017/rails-3-submit-tag-does-not-confirm-while-link-to-does) suggests there was a bug in Rails.
Not sure if that bug still exists or if I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Rails do you use? Rails 3 didn't require `data` param, just `confirm: 'Are you sure?'`